# Child attributes also displayed for in json path while trying to get only root node

Tags: json, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath

For the below sample JSON when I tried to print the root node using `$`: It is printing the entire JSON as a result:

```
{
  "ABC,123": {
    "p1": 100,
    "s1": 66,
    "o1": 10,
     }
}
```

I need to get `ABC,123` using a JSON path.

I tried as `$` it's printing full JSON.

Comment: Is this an escaping problem? Try `System.out.println(jsonPath.get("'ABC,123'").toString());`
Or do you actually want to get the string `ABC,123` as a result?

Comment: Want to get abc,123 as result....this is dynamic value which keeps changing

Answer (score 1):

If you know you are looking for the key name of the first element you could simply use `jsonPath.getMap("$")` of the JSON root, and then get the first key `ABC,123` from the Map/Set:

```
Map<String, String> root = jsonPath.getMap("$");
Set<String> rootKeys = root.keySet();
System.out.println(rootKeys.iterator().next());
```